# MissingPropertyException in SpringSecurityService in my Grails 3.3.8 application

Tags: hibernate, grails, spring-security, grails-orm

Using the grails spring security plugin (3.2.3) I have an app with the standard domain classes that are created using this guide:

https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html#tutorials

It has the following classes specified in the tutorial:

Role.groovy, UserRole.groovy & User.groovy.

User.groovy also has the following code added:

```
static belongsTo = [store: Store]
```

I've added two additional domain classes also:

Store.groovy:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp

class Store {

    String name

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

BookShop.groovy:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp

class BookShop extends Store {

    Boolean isOpen

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I've created a user in Bootstrap.groovy:

```
def init = {

    def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save()

    def testBookShop = new BookShop(name: "BookShop", isOpen: true).save()

    def testUser = new User(username: 'me', password: 'password', store: testBookShop).save()

    UserRole.create testUser, adminRole

    UserRole.withSession {
        it.flush()
        it.clear()
    }

    assert User.count() == 1
    assert Role.count() == 1
    assert UserRole.count() == 1
}
```

I inject my spring security service into my SecureController.groovy and try to render the following:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

class SecureController {

    def springSecurityService

    @Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
    def index() {
        def currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
        render 'Store: ' + currentUser.store.name + ' is open = ' + currentUser.store.isOpen
    }
}
```

I get the following error though:

```
2018-09-10 20:34:26.068 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-2] 
o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : MissingPropertyException 
occurred when processing request: [GET] /secure/index
No such property: isOpen for class: com.mycompany.myapp.BookShop
```

I can get this to work if I specifically unwrap the store:

```
render 'Store: ' + currentUser.store.name + ' is open = ' +
            GrailsHibernateUtil.unwrapIfProxy(currentUser.store).isOpen
```

Just wondering though is there any better solutions to sort this though, I'm updating a large application from grails 2.5.5 to 3.3.8, this worked in 2.5.5 and I'll need to change a lot of code using the method above so hoping for a quick fix, thanks.

Comment: Hello, I can not see the cause of your problem, I just recreated the scenario you describe in your question, grails version, same spring security plugin version. If it seems good, please, look at this repository https://github.com/ilmoralito/springsecurityserviceexample where I follow your example and verify there is no problem. Maybe you passed something subtle overlooked. regards

Comment: Hi user615274, you have solved my problem, the issue appears to be with the version of GORM I was using, if you change it to the following in your github project you should be able to recreate:

    gormVersion=6.1.9.RELEASE

When I changed that to 6.1.10.RELEASE the problem appears to go away, thanks.

Comment: good news, I'm glad it works now

Answer (score 0):

The fix appears to be upgrading GORM from 6.1.9.RELEASE to 6.1.10.RELEASE. Have not seen anything in the upgrade notes to suggest this was a known bug so cannot comment on the exact issue in GORM.

Edit: 
Issue documentated here - https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/1072